# Removing width and height from img tag with preg_replace results in null value

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm working with an image that's processed through a long script in which I cannot modify the function so I'm looking to simply process it's output afterwards with a regex.  Here's what I've got:

I have the following regex pattern:

```
'width\=\"(.*?)\"\sheight\=\"(.*?)\"'
```

I'm trying to remove the width and height from an image tag much like this:

```
<img width="706" height="452" src="/images/logos/partner.png" />
```

When using preg_replace function like so:

```
$img['thumbnail'] = preg_replace(
    'width\=\"(.*?)\"\sheight\=\"(.*?)\"',
    '', 
    $img['thumbnail']);
```

However this returns NULL.

I've tested this using https://regex101.com/ and it appears to be valid.  What am I missing?

Comment: In PHP regexps, you must use delimiters. E.g. `$rx = '~pattern~';`

Comment: Need regex delimiters, can be anything, `'/width="(.*?)\ssheight="(.*?)"/'` or `'~width="(.*?)\ssheight="(.*?)"~'` or   `'#width="(.*?)\ssheight="(.*?)"#'` , etc ...

Comment: Is there a reason why you would choose one delimiter over the other?